# Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodTranslation must be compatible with Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethod::createTranslation():

Tags: php, sylius

I'm following the tutorial : "How to customize a translatable Model?" in Sylius doc.

When I run the command : php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff I got this error :

Fatal error: Declaration of AppBundle\Entity\ShippingMethod::createTranslation(): Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodTranslation must be compatible with Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethod::createTranslation(): Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodTranslationInterface in C:\wamp64\www\acme7\src\AppBundle\Entity\ShippingMethod.php on line 8

Here is my class :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ShippingMethod as BaseShippingMethod;
use Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodTranslation;

class ShippingMethod extends BaseShippingMethod
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
     private $estimatedDeliveryTime;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEstimatedDeliveryTime(): string
    {
        return $this->estimatedDeliveryTime;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $estimatedDeliveryTime
     */
    public function setEstimatedDeliveryTime(string $estimatedDeliveryTime): void
    {
         $this->estimatedDeliveryTime = $estimatedDeliveryTime;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
     protected function createTranslation(): ShippingMethodTranslation
     {
    return new ShippingMethodTranslation();
     }
}
```

Any idea on how to solved this ?

Answer (score 0):

I got some help form the slack of sylius.

As I'm using Sylius v1.0.4

I had to replace :

```
use Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodTranslation;
```

by

```
use Sylius\Component\Shipping\Model\ShippingMethodTranslationInterface;
```

and

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
  protected function createTranslation(): ShippingMethodTranslation
  {
        return new ShippingMethodTranslation();
}
```

by

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function createTranslation(): ShippingMethodTranslationInterface {
    return new ShippingMethodTranslation();
}
```